# Elasticsearch query proximity of terms with regex

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have an issue I am trying to create a query for.  If using a regex for it on a text file the regex would be similar to

```
([A-Za-z]{3} [0-9]{5} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{2})
```

The below would be a potential hits for the regular expression, granted any random set of alphanumeric and numbers that match the pattern should be considered a hit.

```
TEX 11111 222 22
```

However, when the tokens get generated in elasticsearch it will of course create 4 tokens (standard analyzer output below).  Since there are 4 tokens, a standard elasticsearch regexp query wouldn't solve the problem (the regex runs on the generated tokens).

The question would be how do I create an elasticsearch query that would capture a hit out of that series of tokens (I've tried some span_near queries with span_multi, however it produces a lot of false positives even with a slop of 0 and "in_order" set to true).

```
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "TEX 11111 222 22"
}
'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "tex",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "11111",
    "start_offset" : 4,
    "end_offset" : 9,
    "type" : "<NUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "222",
    "start_offset" : 10,
    "end_offset" : 13,
    "type" : "<NUM>",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "22",
    "start_offset" : 14,
    "end_offset" : 16,
    "type" : "<NUM>",
    "position" : 3
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about this specific string then use a match query for "TEX 11111 222 22". If you want to search using regex then What you are looking for is the regexp query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, it isn't this specific string (TEX 11111 222 22) that I am looking for (that was an example).  Unfortunately, a standard regex query doesn't seem to fit since it performs the regex on the tokens created, which would break it up into (tex, 11111, 222, 22)

Comment: Ah I see, what does your document look like. If that string would be the only content of the field you could map it as keyword type  which will not be analyzed and split into tokens so then the regexp query will work. But if you want to find that pattern in a blob of text then that's probably a no go.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a blob of text.  Unfortunately the pattern might be in .01% of the documents processed as well.  However, the requirement is high to find those particular docs.  Unfortunately, of course not the only high priority requirement.